# Problems with my GET form in PHP

Tags: php

I made a GET form recently.But the problem is that it is highly vulnerable.You can inject your an script as below.

```
http://mysite.com/processget.phtml?search=<a href="http://google.com">Hacked</a>
```

I'm able to inject any kind of script into my above URL.I'm actually echoing my GET data using an echo in my BODY,so whenever i enter a malicious script it is being executed in my BODY tag.So now how do i limit this `http://mysite.com/processget.phtml?search=` to just Number,letters and a few symbols which i want.

For ex.The user should only be able to enter

```
http://mysite.com/processget.phtml?search=A123123+*$
```

So can anyof you help me fix this bug.I'm kind of new to PHP,so please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip the tags:

```
echo strip_tags($_GET['search']);
```

Actually, you may want *htmlspecialchars* instead, which escapes the tags instead of removing them so they display as intended:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']);
```

Comment: So it won't allow <a href=" and other scripts like that ?

Comment: No problem! You can accept the answer that you think is most helpful by clicking the tick next to an answer.

Comment: So then how do i make the page redirect to another page after stripping the tag.So ex. After the person enters some tag it should take him to another page.

Comment: What my solution does, is 'escapes' the special characters (`<`, `>` and `&`) so that they are displayed normally on the page instead of being treated as HTML tags. The user may actually want to do a legitimate search with these characters.

Comment: And one more problem I did change the PHP script in my Body but still it is allowing the tags and executing it.

Comment: It works fine for me. Why not post all the code you have now, to, for example, http://codepad.org

Comment: But even if the user does the Tag is getting executed,The tag is not being displayed !!

Comment: No, it doesn't work quite like that. What I meant was that `htmlspecialchars` escapes the user's input so that these characters are treated as normal text instead of real tags.

Comment: This is what i put in my body : You have searched "<?php echo strip_tags($_GET['search']);?>"

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. `strip_tags` just removes tags completely. Try `htmlspecialchars` instead.

Comment: And By the way will my GET form be vulnerable to anything else if i do this ? Will be be totally secured ?

Comment: If you are doing a MySQL query, you'll need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` (or just use MySQLi) before putting it into the query. That's a separate issue altogether.

Comment: No problem, once again, happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!empty($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = htmlentities($_GET['search'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    echo $search;
}
```

Now it's safe.

But if you want to limit to specific symbols, then you need to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can let a user enter whatever you like; the key is to escape the output. Then the string is displayed as desired, rather than included as HTML.

Use a php function like [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)